# Attribute with translation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

am using FOSUserBundle for managing my users. In order to register user, I reused the form of the bundle which meets my needs. Nevertheless, I needed to set some attributes of my fields. This is was done easyly by twig like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
    'placeholder': "Username"} }) }}
```

Now, my goal is to make automatic translation on my placeholder, so I proposed this code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
    'placeholder': "{{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}}"} }) }}
```

This previous code produced an input with placeholder value equal to {{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}}

To get rid of this problem, I tried to set variable for that but symfony generated an error!!!

```
{% set usernameplaceholder = {{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}} %}
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
    'placeholder': usernameplaceholder} }) }}
```

Is there any proposition to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Twig you shouldn't put {{ within {{ (same for {%); think of it as the php tag.

The following should work

> ```
> {% set usernameplaceholder = 'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans %}
> {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
>     'placeholder': usernameplaceholder} }) }}
> ```

OR

> {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
>       'placeholder': 'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans} }) }}